# Cannot resolve app:srcCompat="@mipmap/fail"

Tags: android-studio

I have imported a project from SVN. I get following error:

`cannot resolve symbol "@mipmap/fail"`

at line:

`app:srcCompat="@mipmap/fail"` in one of the xml file.

I do not what I should be looking for. I am new to Android Programming.

Please let me know what details I need to look in to.

Thank you.

Comment: check your project structure and tell if the file `fail` exists. If yes, post the path to where does it exist